# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No method found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 2 copies of the same Xamarin Forms project. They are identical wrt XAML and code. Targetting Android, one project builds and runs ok. The other gets error in LoadFromXaml() which is called in InitializeComponent() in MainPage.xaml.g.cs.

"Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 35:32. No method Help_OnClick found on type NflCalcXF.MainPage"

Help_OnClick does exist in the code behind, and in fact when you right click on it in XAML and choose 'Go to definition', it goes to it.

As I mentioned, the other project, which I retrieved from backup, is identical, but does not have this problem.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: "Help_OnClick does exist in the code behind" is the issue. Look at your XAML there you have the reference to the "Help_OnClick"  on the button/label for the Clicked event. 
If you don't need that Clicked event to be assigned remove that. If you require that event on Clicked then you should Implement the Help_OnClick method on code behind.

Comment: As I stated in the question, the method *is* implimented in the code behind.

Comment: By Code behind do u mean, xaml.cs or PageModel? That method has to be in xaml.cs, also check if you have the same namespace in your xaml and xaml.cs file. Also delete bin and obj files and clean and rebuild. MainPage.xaml.g.cs is a metadata.

Comment: Help_OnClick method is implemented in xaml.cs. Xaml specifies same namespace as xaml.cs. I have tried deleting all bin & obj files and also clean and rebuild solution.

Comment: Please post the xaml and xaml.cs files.

Comment: coincidently I am facing same issue. Earlier all backups from across Laptop and PC were working when copied either side. But today gave this specific error. I am still struggling. As you said I too had already deleted bin and obj .vs folders but not resolved yet. Created new instance also but still no luck. It stucks at same error in .g.cs file. Did you find any solution till now?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create `Xaml`, it creates a cs file and auto generated cs(`xaml.g.cs`) as well inorder to define some logic. Whatever you do in `Xaml` like `x:Name`, event(like `Clicked`) definition etc will generate some code as well to auto connect with cs code(you might have noticed class has partial keyword in it). Once you define an event it should be on the cs file to connect as well.

Thats the reason you should add

```
void Help_OnClick(objecxt sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //then some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution Finally after hours of efforts trying each and every possibilities.
And finally I tried to recollect what was major changes I had done in last publish (and then took backup).

**So I found that I had changed the Android->Android Options->linking property in Android from 'None' to 'SDK and User Assemblies'.

I changed back to 'None' and it worked smoothly in first build only.**

Surprising. Still if any one can give a valid technical details for this would be great. And hope this was only the issue. if anyone gets same resolution trying this let me know. May be in near future I would try myself.